# Hide Y-axis labels when data is not displayed in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a Chart.js bar graph displaying two sets of data: Total SQL Queries and Slow SQL Queries. I have Y-axis labels for each respective set of data. The graph can be seen below:

[image: SQL Performance graph]

When I toggle one of the sets of data to not display, the corresponding Y-axis labels still display. When interpreting the graph, this is a bit confusing. As seen below:

[image]

**My question:** How can I hide the Y-axis labels of any set of data that is currently not being displayed?

This is how I currently have my chart set up:

```
<canvas id="SQLPerformanceChart" minHeight="400"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    var data = {
        labels: labelArray,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Total SQL Queries",
            fill: false,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: "green",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)",
            yAxisID: "y-axis-0",
            data: totalQueriesArray
        }, {
            label: "Slow SQL Queries",
            fill: false,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: "orange",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3)",
            yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
            data: slowQueriesArray,
        }]
    };

    var options = {
        animation: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                position: "left",
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Total SQL Queries'
                },
                id: "y-axis-0"
            }, {
                position: "right",
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Slow SQL Queries'
                },
                id: "y-axis-1"
            }]
        },
        tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'single',
            callbacks: {
                title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return data.label;
                },
                beforeLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    if (tooltipItem.index == 24) {
                        return data.labels[tooltipItem.index] + " - Now";
                    } else {
                        return data.labels[tooltipItem.index] + " - " + data.labels[(tooltipItem.index) + 1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById("SQLPerformanceChart");
    var SQLPerformanceChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: options
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add a callback function to legends onClick:

```
var options = {
        animation: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                position: "left",
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Total SQL Queries'
                },
                id: "y-axis-0"
            }, {
                position: "right",
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Slow SQL Queries'
                },
                id: "y-axis-1"
            }]
        },
        legend: {
        onClick: function(event, legendItem) {
            //get the index of the clicked legend
            var index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
            //toggle chosen dataset's visibility
            SQLPerformanceChart.data.datasets[index].hidden = 
                !SQLPerformanceChart.data.datasets[index].hidden;
            //toggle the related labels' visibility
            SQLPerformanceChart.options.scales.yAxes[index].display =                 
                !SQLPerformanceChart.options.scales.yAxes[index].display;
            SQLPerformanceChart.update();
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this permanently hides the labels. I am trying to hide the labels only when the data is toggled to not display. If the data is toggled back to display, then the labels should re-appear.

Comment: Thanks, it's an improvement! But now clicking a legend item only causes the labels to disappear. By overriding the onClick function, the default behaviors of the onClick function no longer occur (e.g. the data no longer disappears, there is no strikethrough on the legend item, etc.). I'm currently trying to resolve this.

Comment: I've added two more rows to solve the mentioned issues

Comment: Thank you for your smart way of turning on/off by using "!"

Answer (score 1):

This solution applies if you are **using [angular-chartjs](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)**, and if you want to **apply this behaviour to all displayed charts**.

If you want to skip to the code, **check this [fiddlejs](https://jsfiddle.net/merou8ax/2/)**.

You can also check this other [fiddlejs](https://jsfiddle.net/r3d7scnz/) to check the **default Angular-Chartjs** behaviour.

---

## Step by step:

I use the [first chart example in angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#directives), so this will be the final result after clicking:

[image]

```
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">  
        <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
        chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options"
        chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick">
      </canvas>
    </div>
```

1. Replace the handler of the global Chart:

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick = function (e, legendItem) {
  var idx = legendItem.datasetIndex;

  // IMPORTANT charts will be created in the second and third step
  var chart = charts[e.srcElement.id];
  chart.options.scales.yAxes[idx].display = !chart.options.scales.yAxes[idx].display;

  var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(idx);
  // See controller.isDatasetVisible comment
  meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !chart.data.datasets[idx].hidden : null;

  chart.update();

};
```

2. Create a global variable `charts` so we can get access each of the charts with the canvas id:

```
var charts = {};
```

3. Fill up the charts variables using the `chart-create` event:

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("MainController", function ($scope) {
  $scope.$on('chart-create', function (event, chart) {
    charts[chart.chart.canvas.id] = chart;
  });

  $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
  $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
  $scope.data = [...
```

I wish there would be a better way of getting a chart from the canvas id, but as far as I know this is the [suggested way by the developers](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/464).

Answer (score 1):

This solution applies if you are using ng2-charts with chart.js and Angular 7^ and if you want to apply this behavior to all displayed charts.

```
    import Chart from chart.js
    Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick = function (e: MouseEvent, chartLegendLabelItem: ChartLegendLabelItem) {
  const idx: number = chartLegendLabelItem.datasetIndex;
  const chart = this.chart;
  chart.options.scales.yAxes[idx].display = !chart.options.scales.yAxes[idx].display;

  const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(idx);
  meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !chart.data.datasets[idx].hidden : null;

  chart.update();

};
```

or for local configuration

```
    legend: <ChartLegendOptions>{
         onClick: function (e: MouseEvent, chartLegendLabelItem:ChartLegendLabelItem) {
      const idx: number = chartLegendLabelItem.datasetIndex;
      const chart = this.chart;
      chart.options.scales.yAxes[idx].display = 
     !chart.options.scales.yAxes[idx].display;

      const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(idx);
      meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? 
             !chart.data.datasets[idx].hidden : null;

      chart.update();

    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

I came along this problem using v3.8.0, none of the obove worked for me.
This code works for me.
Note I'm storing all my chart instances in a Map because I have multiple charts on the same page.

```
var instances = new Map();
```

When createing the incances I put them there.

and now the hiding of the y axis label and data on legend click:

```
 onClick: function (event, legendItem) {
                            var instance = instances.get(event.chart.id);
                            var meta = instance.getDatasetMeta(legendItem.datasetIndex);
                            var newValue = !meta.yScale.options.display;
                            meta.hidden = meta.yScale.options.display;
                            meta.yScale.options.display = newValue;
                            instance.update();
                        }
```